# PHP mySQL INSERT syntax error?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newbie and I've been trying for over an hour to solve this simple query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tracks` (artistID, albumID, format, trackID, niceTitle, title, trackNumber, description, pictureURL, playCount) VALUES('$artistID', '$albumID[$i]', 'hq','$ID[0]', '$trackName', '$title', '$j', '$description', '$pictureURL', '$playCount'") or die(mysql_error());
```

I just get this error every time:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I've done mysql_escape_string() on all variables too. Any ideas?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: You are missing the `)` for the VALUES

Comment: Uff, 20 years later, people still using deprecated stuff :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the final closing `)`:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tracks` (artistID, albumID, format, trackID, niceTitle, title, trackNumber, description, pictureURL, playCount) VALUES('$artistID', '$albumID[$i]', 'hq','$ID[0]', '$trackName', '$title', '$j', '$description', '$pictureURL', '$playCount')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2):

You have no ending parenthesis ")" in your query